# REST API authentication for multiple devices

Tags: laravel, rest, lumen

In my website a user can login in 3 ways

1. Pass the email & password
2. Login with Google and Facebook
3. Login with IOT device(with the device id)

Now I am confused on how to authenticate a user. For the first option I can use the JWT token but I have no idea on how to authenticate the Google and IOT devices.

**Note**: My API is in Lumen. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Laravel Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite) to use Google and Facebook API as one of your login options.

but about your IOT device you need to create a custom function in Laravel after checking device id of IOT device with your code you can use below code to login your user and give them a JWT token.

```
Auth::login($user);
```

note: `$user` is your user to login and you can get it using:

```
$user = User::find(write_your_user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint

For multiple API tokens use Sanctum.

Sanctum allows each user of your application to generate multiple API tokens for their account.

Reference:
Introduction:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum